# Referencing constants in .srv from Python

Tags: ros, python, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given the file:

- foo.srv

  ```
    string service_name = foo_service
    string in
    ---
    string out
  ```

In my C++ code, `my_project::foo::Request::service_name` works as expected, but how do I do this in Python? I do:

```
from my_project.srv import foo
```

at the head of the file, but in the code `foo.service_name`, `fooRequest.service_name`, `foo.fooRequest.service_name` all fail. I can see `service_name = 'foo_service'` in the generated `_foo.py` file, so I think it's a problem in my code, not my build process.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231884/referencing-constants-in-.srv-from-python/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2016-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked on my system for some example services with constants:

```
/opt/ros/jade/share$ grep -r "=" * | grep \\.srv
...
gazebo_msgs/srv/GetJointProperties.srv:uint8 FIXED       = 3                # 0 DOF
...
```

Then

```
$ rossrv show GetJointProperties
[gazebo_msgs/GetJointProperties]:
string joint_name
---
uint8 REVOLUTE=0
uint8 CONTINUOUS=1
uint8 PRISMATIC=2
uint8 FIXED=3
uint8 BALL=4
...
```

So it was in the response.

In python:

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import GetJointPropertiesResponse
print GetJointPropertiesResponse.FIXED
```

also:

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import GetJointProperties
print GetJointProperties._response_class.FIXED
```

And the output is `3` as expected.  I didn't find an existing example with a string constant so tried adding my own, and it also worked the same.

This shows what is in the class:

```
print GetJointPropertiesResponse.__dict__.keys()
['_type', 'BALL', '_has_header', 'PRISMATIC', '_slot_types', 'CONTINUOUS', '__module__', 'rate', 'serialize', 'FIXED', '__init__', 'deserialize_numpy', 'success', 'deserialize', 'type', 'UNIVERSAL', '_full_text', '_md5sum', '__doc__', '_get_types', '__slots__', 'damping', 'REVOLUTE', 'position', 'status_message', 'serialize_numpy']
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2016-04-14**:
Thank you; `_response_class` was the magic I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even if this is an old question I wanted to answer it since I came across the same problem.

According to the [PyStyleGuide](http://wiki.ros.org/PyStyleGuide) is a protected member of the class, thus accessing this is not the way it is meant to be.

A cleaner way to access the constants (IMHO) is to include the classes which are accessed with the `_request_class` and `_response_class` members.

In the example given above this would be:

```
from my_package.srv include MySrv
from my_package.srv include MySrvRequest
from my_package.srv include MySrvResponse

# Do something with:
MySrvRequest.MY_REQUEST_CONSTANT
MySrvResponse.MY_RESPONSE_CONSTANT
```

---

Originally posted by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) with karma: 65 on 2018-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1